# Shortcut key for "execute query" in SQL view

Tags: ms-access

Is there a shortcut for Microsoft Access Query Editor to execute the SQL? This clicking drives me mad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not exactly a hot key combo, you have to press each key in sequence:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd> to switch to table view

<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> to switch to design view

If you right click on the ribbon's button to switch to different views (design, table, sql, etc) you can add the button to the quick access bar. With that done you can then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> (where # is the number for whatever position the button is on the quick access bar).

Answer (score 14):

Newer Office applications support common keyboard shortcuts from earlier versions, so in the Access query builder we can use <kbd>Alt+V</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> for Design view, <kbd>Alt+V</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> for dataSheet view, and <kbd>Alt+V</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd> for sQl view.

To run an action query (e.g., UPDATE, DELETE) <kbd>Alt+Q</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> (for Query > Run) works too.

(Tested in Access 2010 and 2013; probably works in Access 2007 as well.)

Answer (score 10):

```
Ctrl + .    from query design to datasheet
Ctrl + ,    from datasheet to query design
```

Mnemonically, it helps that these are keys for `>` and `<`:

```
Ctrl + >    from query design to datasheet
Ctrl + <    from datasheet to query design
```

I didn't show them that way above because that would suggest you also press the `Shift` key.

These commands cycle through various views, including pivots.  I'm not interested in Access' pivot feature and I don't wish to accidently launch it, so that might be reason to use one of the other methods.

Answer (score 4):

To run a query in access 2013 here is the keyboard shortcuts

```
F10, J, Q, G
```

Try it yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no similar path to return to Design View.

Comment: Hi @Smandoli, you can use Alt + H, W, D to return to Design View.

Comment: On German version of Access in Microsoft 365 as of 2022 (version 2206), press `Alt` (or `F10`), then `JQ`, then `F`. Once you hit `Alt` (or `F10`), available possibilities will light up.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a great shortcut for any of you who customize your toolbar.  For most of you Millenials out there, your toolbar is the little group of three buttons at the top left of your Access window that has never made much sense to you... :o)  It's a real time saver if you figure out how to use it.

Add the RUN button to the far left of your toolbar.  Now - <kbd>ALT</kbd> then <kbd>1</kbd>  (not <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) will run your query.  Press these buttons one after the other, unlike a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> shortcut.

Gig 'Em

Answer (score 1):

I just made this AutoHotKey script that will take you straight to the SQL Editor view in Access.

Access 2016:

```
f8::
SetKeyDelay 100
Send {Alt}cqd!c{Alt}{Left 4}{Down}{Enter}{Alt}{Right 4}{Alt}^{F10}
Return
```

Access 2010:

```
f8::
SetKeyDelay 100
Send {Alt}cqd!c{Alt}{Left 4}{Down}{Enter 2}{Alt}{Right 4}{Alt}^{F10}
Return
```

Instructions:

1. Download and install [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
2. Create a text file named `whatever.ahk` and copy the above script into it. Save.
3. Double-click the file. This won't execute the script, but will load AHK into memory.
4. Open your Access database.
5. Hit the F8 key and the script will run, and land you in the SQL Editor.

Note #1: You don't need to double-click the file each time - once it's running it will keep running until you close it. You can see the icon in your system tray. All you have to do is hit F8 each time you want to open the SQL Editor.

Note #2: You can substitute F8 with any key/combo of your choice, just be careful not to collide with existing keyboard shortcuts. F8 doesn't seem to do anything in Access (natively) so it works great. I got so sick of clicking my mouse 10X all over Access every time I wanted to open SQL Editor -- you'll love this!